# Are there any ways to embed a browser in Android app?

Tags: android, cordova, browser, chromium-embedded

I'm working on a project that needs to manage requests(html/javascript) and many more other things. I Used [Chromiumembedded](http://code.google.com/p/chromiumembedded/) for windows. Now I need something like that for android.

I've searched about android programming and spent some time on [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/). As I know it opens a webview and have some javascript API for some device features like camera. So Phonegap is not going to help me.

I wonder if there is any way to embed Chrome or any other browser that can be embedded in an android app?

Comment: What's wrong with embedding a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)?

Comment: Webview is the answer. It has got enormous capability. You should experiment with it.

Comment: As far as I understand, chromiumembedded is a capability to your desktop application to have a browser, so developers won't get to develop their own browser into that app. WebView in Android is the equal to chromiumembedded in PC.

Comment: A great lake is WebView does not support **queryString**. example: `webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/foo.html?a=1");` shows error. But using phonegap solves this problem.

Comment: Get rid of the query parameters. Find another way to pass the data into the app, such as by injecting an object via `addJavaScriptInterface()` which the Web page uses to pull data from.

Answer (score 6):

Android has a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) component that is basically a browser. You can place it anywhere in your application and you can enable JavaScript that is disabled by default. Supports HTML 5. I use it in production and fully recommend.

Unfortunately the 3.x versions have a [bug not supporting string query](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17535) that may be present inside URLs of some pages. In the bug website this issue shows as closed and fixed. I was even not aware about it as we use 4.1.0 for everything. The bug is already fixed with that release. For earlier versions, some workarounds are available [here](http://bricolsoftconsulting.com/2012/05/15/fixing-the-broken-honeycomb-and-ics-webview/).

Comment: [Read the comment Above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535346/are-there-any-ways-to-embed-a-browser-in-android-app#comment20271666_14535346)

Comment: So webview can't help me. I have to use queryString.

Comment: Say that you only support versions since 4.1 and later. Depending on your target audience, may or may not be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `android.webkit.WebView` it's the equivalent of the iOS's `UIWebView`

Comment: Thanks for your participation, please red the [Comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535346/are-there-any-ways-to-embed-a-browser-in-android-app#comment20271666_14535346)

Answer (score 0):

Use android.webkit.WebView

Set the view, for example:

```
WebView mywebview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

and load the url of application:

```
mywebview.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

or

```
mywebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html_no_copy/test.html");
```

and for enable javascript in your application, set:

```
WebSettings webSettings = mywebview.getSettings();
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Try and read the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: I think should read the [comment Above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535346/are-there-any-ways-to-embed-a-browser-in-android-app#comment20271666_14535346), too