# Use Chrome as render engine for Android webview

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352654/use-firefox-as-render-engine-for-android-webview) very similar to what I need but I need chrome. Because of many reasons android webView (as I discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535346/are-there-any-ways-to-embed-a-browser-in-android-app) ) is not compatible with my application's requirements.

So are there any ways to *Use **Chrome** as **render engine** for **Android webview***

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is coming as the default in Android 4.4 KitKat. See https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/webview/overview

Comment: The problem with this is that WebView on KitKat uses V8 version 30. (But V8 is on version 45-47), So your appliction could be incompatible.

https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview

Comment: @eveevans Google has not done a good job of keeping this page updated. It currently lists up to WebView v36 but my device has v49.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a proof of concept for a view that uses the Chromium code and has a WebView-like API.
https://github.com/pwnall/chromeview

Make sure to read the *Issues* section in the Readme. This is merely a starting point, it's not ready for production use.

Comment: Do you know when they plan to use Chromium as the default webview engine?

Comment: I don't have any inside information on Google's plans. There is daily activity in the android_webview directory in the Chromium source tree, which means they're at least working towards it. Given the current issues, and the timeline for key lime pie, I would guess we won't have it there. So... 2014 at the earliest?

Comment: I'm from the future, still nothing.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Hyangelo's answer, if anyone needs to support Chrome for Android versions 4.0-4.3, you can use [crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/).