# Does installing Chrome on Android Jelly Bean (4.1-4.3) make WebView use Chrome for rendering?

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-webview

If a user installs [Google Chrome for Android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.chrome) on an Android device running Jelly Bean (4.1-4.3, API level 16-18), do all [WebViews](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) then use Chrome for rendering? I'm asking because as a way to [support Flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox) on such devices, I'm considering telling users to install Google Chrome.

Comment: No it doesnt. Consider crosswalk: https://crosswalk-project.org/

Comment: Seems it became the default with 4.4 https://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/migrating.html see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/14537083/32453