# How to integrate the chrome[-like] browser as part of the Android app?

Tags: android, qt, google-chrome, webview, webrtc

Our app is built on Qt-C++ which acts as a backend. For front end, we invoke browser command in a given platform (Windows, Mac, Linux). Now the Javascript of browser and the C++ of backend communicate via WebSockets. All the rendering happens fine and app works well.
[Note: It turns out that, Qt's Web-engine is not a good option due to its size and inflexibility.]

However in the case of mobile apps there are few concerns.

- We cannot invoke the chrome browser as we do in Desktops, because the main app goes in background and brings the "Google Chrome" (browser) app in foreground
- The default choice is Webview, but there are few limitations of it as noted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22459735/is-there-an-alternative-to-webview)

Our app is not heavy in rendering. Though it requires playing of video and webrtc (which is available with some of the Android webviews).

What is the best solution when the android app requires the features of Google chrome browser app?

Related: [Are there any ways to embed a browser in Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14535346/are-there-any-ways-to-embed-a-browser-in-android-app)